# How do I remove i18N RESTEASY log messages?

Tags: java, jax-rs, netty, resteasy

I am using netty and resteasy to implement a REST interface. I get these entries in my log files:

```
2016-09-14 13:29:31.116 DEBUG i18n getInvoker() - RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /director/logmessage
2016-09-14 13:29:31.126 DEBUG i18n getInvoker() - RESTEASY002315:   PathInfo: /director/sendresult
2016-09-14 13:29:31.154 DEBUG i18n getInvoker() - RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /director/logmessage
2016-09-14 13:29:31.161 DEBUG i18n getInvoker() - RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /director/logmessage
```

The package i18n seems to be in the native java distribution: `com.sun.imageio.plugins`, I have tried to change the log4 jlevels as follows:

```
<appender name="netty" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="file" value="atf_logs/atf_http.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %c{1} %M() - %m%n" />
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
</appender>

<logger name="com.sun.imageio.plugins" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="netty" />
</logger>
```

I have also tried:

```
<logger name="org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.i18n" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="netty" />
</logger>
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and adjust the following for log4j:

```
<logger name="org.jboss.resteasy.core" level="INFO" />
<logger name="org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl" level="INFO" />
<logger name="org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server" level="INFO" />
```

See here for more information http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.0.GA/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#RESTEasyLogging

Comment: I added these two options to log4j.xml:                                             `<logger name="org.apache.http" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="netty" />
    </logger>
    
    <logger name="org.jboss.resteasy" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="netty" />
    </logger>`